# Swift2: Why doesn't this Dictionary extension compiles?

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary

Xcode7 throws:

`Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Key,Value>' with an index of type 'T'`

What am I missing here?

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    func boolOr<T:StringLiteralConvertible>(fall: Bool, key: T) -> Bool {
        return (self[key] as? Bool) ?? fall
    }
}
```

Trying to make it a `String` also doesn't work (I get the same error with `String` instead `T`)

```
let s = "\(key)"
return self[s] as? Bool ?? fall
```

Comment: If you declare your `extension` with a constraint like `Key: StringLiteralConvertible`, in your method the `<T:StringLiteralConvertible>` declaration looks redundant to me, since the `Key` type is already satisfies that.

Comment: I agree, but than what type should `key` be? Simply removing the conformation of `T` to `StringLiteralConvertible` doesn't help, neither do making `key` explicitly `String`

Comment: You can declare it as `Key`

Comment: Tried that too... I get `inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Key'`

Comment: Why do you put a constraint on the key type at all ??

Comment: I also tried without any constraint, but I still get the same annoying complaint from Xcode...

Comment: How do you expect `self[key] as? Bool` to pass where key is StringLiteralConvertible ?

Comment: @zellb you can see from the comments that I tried many different things, those that made sense to me and eventually some that didn't (because... well.... swift compiler). Do you have an idea how to make it so it *does* work?

Comment: I still don't know what exactly do you need. Declaring your function like `    func boolOr(fall: Bool, key: Key) -> Bool {
        return ((self)[key] as? Bool) ?? fall
    }
` will work but will also return fall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the type constraint
on the `boolOr()` method is not necessary:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    func boolOr(fall: Bool, key: Key) -> Bool {
        return (self[key] as? Bool) ?? fall
    }
}
```

because the key type is already restricted in the extension declaration.
Your code does not compile because `<T:StringLiteralConvertible>`
introduces a local type placeholder `T` which is unrelated to the
`Key` type of the dictionary.

But actually I don't see why you want to put a constraint on the
key type at all:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: AnyObject {
    func boolOr(fall: Bool, key: Key) -> Bool {
        return (self[key] as? Bool) ?? fall
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it works, so first of all thank you. But for the sake of my education, since `Key` is not a type, but some sort of a protocol, how can `key` be of type `Key`? Or does `Key` considered a type?

Comment: @AvielGross `Key` is a type that must adopt hashable protocol

Comment: @AvielGross: The Swift dictionary is defined as `public struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> { ... }`, so `Key` is the *type placeholder* for the key type.